# Opening a pipe and delays in parsing the output in Perl

Tags: perl, pipe, delay

I am trying to do a fairly simple process using Perl. A snippet of the code:

```
open(FH,"<command> |") or die "Could not run command .. $!\n";

print "After open\n";

while(<FH>) 
{
     print "I am inside loop\n";
     <process..something>
}
```

I am seeing some inexplicable delays when the while() is called. I see the open took 9-10ms to run ( which is within range ), however I do see 200 - 250ms delay between the messages "After open" and "I am inside loop".

Has anyone seen anything like this before ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rajib

Comment: Well, what "_command_" are you running and what does it do?  You get inside `while` only once something _is_ read by `<FH>`, so that entirely depends on what that "_command_" is doing. If it were to sleep for 2 seconds and then print, then your `while (<FH>)` will sit there for 2 seconds.

Comment: Note that lexical filehandles (`my $fh`) and three-argument `open` are recommended, and better.

Comment: I am running a database command db2pd -db <dbname> -active whose output happens pretty much instantaneously ( if I try it outside the program ).

Comment: Ah, OK.  Please add this information to the question, by editing it.  (Always try to include all relevant info, and this surely is.)  Yeah, that time is huge. It seems clear that this related to that program that you run.   The command's buffering may behave differently when printing to the console.There is nothing out of order in the code.  Except, again: `open my $fh, '-|', @comm  or die ... ` and `while (my $line = <$fh>) { }` (or `while (<$fh>)`, of course).

Comment: What is the situation that makes a quarter of a second an unacceptable delay?

Comment: I am looking to trigger if say a query runs for more than 50ms .. This is for an OLTP env the avg response times of the queries are 0.5ms but some outliers are taking anywhere between 50-100ms. This 200-250ms gap is defeating its purpose. I'll try the 3 option format of open as suggested above and see if it helps. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly because the output from *<command>* is buffered until either the buffer fills up or the process terminates

You can probably get around this using `unbuffer`, which pretends to the command that it is outputting to a terminal

Try using this instead

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'unbuffer <command>' or die "Could not run command: $!\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I really appreciate all the help. After I used zdim's suggestion of using the 3 option format of open() the times came down to ~150-160ms, but when I used Borodin's command it came down to 30-35ms!!

Comment: The final code for open I used was:

      open $FH, '-|', 'unbuffer db2pd -db $db -active 2>/dev/null' or die "Could not run command.. $!\n";

I used the 2>/dev/null to remove the sh: unbuffer not found error message in my log file. 

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @rssarkar: That doesn't look at all right. You're opening a pipe ***to*** the command instead of ***from*** it, and you shouldn't be getting a `unbuffer not found` message. Are you sure your system has `unbuffer`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I had a typo in my above command, it should have been '|-'. The AIX system where I was testing doesn't have unbuffer command which is why the times went down to 35ms .. :-) I switched to a Linux system where the unbuffer command is there and I see the times to be the same if I use the unbuffer command or not.